# using IF statements with NSData converted in to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When trying to use an IF statement to call a method from data that has been received though bluetooth it dose not marry up

Is there still extra data packets in there that I need to remove?

```
-(IBAction) btnSend:(id) sender
{
    //---convert an NSString object to NSData---
    NSData* data;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:txtMessage.text];
    data = [str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self mySendDataToPeers:data];
}

- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data
            fromPeer:(NSString *)peer
           inSession:(GKSession *)session
             context:(void *)context {

    //---convert the NSData to NSString---
    NSString* str;
    str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString* test = str;

    NSString* up = @"up";

    if (test == up)
    {
        [self up];


    }
    else
    {
        str = @"Not Vaild";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data received"
                                                        message:str
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Xcode? Nothing at all, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
if (test == up)
```

with

```
if ([test isEqualToString:up])
```